# Problema con inicializar Select en Materialize CSS

Tags: html, css, materialize

Es mi primera vez usando este `framework`, estoy intentado colocar un `select`, sin embargo no me aparece absolutamente nada más que el `label` y sobre puesto en el lugar donde esta el botón, si alguien me pudiera decir como se hace o en que me equivoco se los agradecería mucho.

Así es como me aparece:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí muestro la manera en como inicié el `select`, y como lo he colocado, esta igual que en la página oficial porque estoy tratando de seguir la documentación, sin embargo me he atorado.

Mi código:

```html
<title>Document</title>

    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('select').formSelect();
        });
    </script>


</head>

<body>

    <div class="section container">
        <div class="row">
            <form class="col s12">
                <div class="row card-panel">
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre" id="nombre" class="validate" required>
                        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input type="text" id="apellido" class="validate" required>
                        <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input type="email" id="email">
                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <select>
                          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
                          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                          <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                        </select>
                        <label>Materialize Select</label>
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn" type="submit">ENVIAR</button>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hola. Prueba a anidar el button dentro de `<div class="input-field col s12">aquí</div>` sospecho que con eso baste para que no se pisen. En cuanto al select no veo claro por qué no se ve en la imagen. Revisa los atributos del objeto haciendo click con botón derecho en la zona situada arriba del label. suele mostrar una opción como inspeccionar elemento

Comment: En el select solo me aparece el label que dice `materialize select` y no se ve el select realmente ni las opciones...

Comment: Ponle id al select y en el label asigna el atributo for="selectid"

Answer (score 1):

También estoy aprendiendo, pero por lo que veo no te carga la inicialización con JQuery, si lo cmabias por JAvascript si funciona.

```html
<title>Document</title>

    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script> 
    
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="section container">
        <div class="row">
            <form class="col s12">
                <div class="row card-panel">
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="input-field col s6">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre" id="nombre" class="validate" required>
                            <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s6">
                            <input type="text" id="apellido" class="validate" required>
                            <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <input type="email" id="email">
                            <label for="email">Email:</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col s12">
                            <select>
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
                            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                            </select>
                            <label>Materialize Select</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <button class="btn" type="submit">ENVIAR</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
            var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
        });
    </script>
```

Me tome la libertad de modificarte la tarjeta, espero que te sirva, un saludo.